# Is "bared fruit" grammatical?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, orthography

> Am I the only one whos athletic career bared fruit?

Is this sentence correct grammatically?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it grammatically; it's very odd semantically, unless you competed in peeling bananas.

Answer (score 3):

"Am I the only one *whose* athletic career *bore* fruit?" might be the construction you're looking for.

Note that the proper possessive form of "who" is "whose", not "who's" (let alone "whos"
 [*sic*]) and "bore" is the past tense of "bear".

Comment: And "bared" is the past tense of "bare", which is to make naked, to uncover, or to expose. Example: she bared a baby boy = she took the baby's clothes off. Compare: she bore a baby boy = she had one (produced one, as it were). Your example: your career bared fruit = it peeled the fruit!? That can't be right. Compare: your career bore fruit = it produced a result, an effect, an outcome.

Answer (score 2):

Compare with the right to bare arms:

[image]

(Larry the Cable Guy, whose material I have never listened to and so cannot comment on, has bared his arms in this picture.) Humour's dreadfully subjective, so I trust I haven't offended you.

I'm voting for Deepak's answer.