# Can a sentence be grammatical without making sense?

Tags: grammaticality, semantics, logic

> Am I the only one whose athletic career bared fruit?

While this sentence doesn’t make logical sense, seeing as it should be "bore fruit", is it still grammatically correct? Can a sentence that makes no logical sense at all still be considered ‘correct’ or ‘grammatical’?

And if the answer to that is yes, then how does one distinguish between something that is grammatical and something that is not, if the meaning is not relevant?

---

*Note:* This question is different from the previous question (which it has been marked as a duplicate of) in that it asks specifically whether a sentence that makes no logical sense can still be considered grammatical, despite its not making sense.

Comment: Please stop reposting! http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/226259/i-need-to-know-if-a-sentence-is-grammatically-correct/226264#226264

Comment: This sentence seems to confuse *to bear* 'to carry' with *to bare* 'to reveal'.

Comment: @Anonym I am fully aware of the difference in meaning of those two words.

Comment: @user2268251 My point is that the idiom is *to bear fruit*, like a tree, not *to bare fruit*.

Comment: @Anonym I understand that that is your point. However I'm not looking for a different way to write the idiom. I'm merely looking to see if a sentence that's logically flawed, where a thing (career) does a thing (bare) it couldn't possibly do to a thing (fruit), is still grammatically correct.

Comment: @user2268251 Whoops. I've just reread the question; I had a serious lapse there. A sentence need not make sense to be grammatical. *The termite dusted the pantry made of gourmet elves* is also grammatical, since it follows all the rules, but even more nonsensical than your sentence.

Comment: Depending on the meaning you want, all of these verb forms are potentially grammatical: "bore fruit" (produced fruit), "bored fruit" (drilled holes in fruit or filled fruit with ennui), "bared fruit" (revealed fruit without any covering), "beared fruit" (gave fruit to bears). Since you didn't ask, I won't illustrate the senses in which "beered fruit," "biered fruit," and "bearded fruit" may also be used grammatically.

Comment: @SvenYargs I’d love a career bearding fruit. I suppose if you’re a hair dresser in the Castro, you might be said to have a career unbearding fruits …

Comment: @user2268251 The standard sentence used to show how completely grammatical sentences can be utter nonsense is [_colourless green ideas sleep furiously_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorless_green_ideas_sleep_furiously), invented by Noam Chomsky. His argument was that though the sentence itself makes no sense whatsoever, it is grammatical, unlike its transposition, _*furiously sleep ideas green colourless_, which is grammatical **and** semantic balderdash.

Comment: It depends on your definition of 'grammatical'. According to the one mainly encountered on ELU, 'It's grammatical, (but that's about the only good thing you can say about it).' If you use Wordnet's sense 2b (
2. grammatical - conforming to the rules of grammar or usage accepted by native speakers) (usage: the way in which a word or phrase is normally and correctly used_Google), it's not.

Comment: I have clarified the question tweaked your edit (since what you had written was basically “this isn’t a duplicate because I didn’t get the answers I wanted on the first one”, which doesn’t work), since I believe the way _this_ question is worded is on-topic here, and a fundamentally different question than the original one. I have also voted to reopen it.

Comment: I also agree with Janus. And he did a very good edit.

Comment: Olympic class grape peelers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is grammatically correct - but don't ever use it unless it is very clear that it's meant to be a pun - otherwise everyone will just assume you don't know how to spell.

Comment: +1 for being the only answer thus far that actually answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

As for whether it's grammatically correct, I can't say it better than StoneyB did yesterday: "There's nothing wrong with it grammatically; it's very odd semantically, unless you competed in peeling bananas."

As for whether something can be grammatically correct even though it doesn't make logical sense, there is plenty of grammatically-correct nonsense out there. I'm thinking of Alice in Wonderland / Through the Looking Glass, wherein are to be found poems that defy my understanding.

As for whether one can evaluate whether something is grammatical without caring about the meaning, I'd say yes, definitely--"[Premasticate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/premasticate#English) the [frontonasal](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/frontonasal#English) [globe sight](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/globe_sight#English)" (made using [random English words from the wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Special:RandomInCategory/English_lemmas#English), yay!) is completely fine grammatically--but I think that might only be true with real English words. I think maybe if you make up your own words, or borrow from other languages, we can no longer say whether it's grammatically correct. We have to know whether a word is a verb or a noun, and from there whether it's conjugated correctly, or whether it's singular or plural--that sort of thing...

Comment: Would you say that whether this is grammatically correct or not depends on whether your definition of 'grammar' is the narrower linguistic one or the broader layman's definition?

Comment: I think if one's career is as an ecdysiast then they bare something.

Comment: I rewrote my answer completely. @user2268251, by the narrower definition, do you mean what the following calls "Descriptive grammar"?

Comment: "Descriptive grammar refers to the structure of a language as it is actually used by speakers and writers. Prescriptive grammar refers to the structure of a language as certain people think it should be used.

Both kinds of grammar are concerned with rules--but in different ways. Specialists in descriptive grammar (called linguists) study the rules or patterns that underlie our use of words, phrases, clauses, and sentences. On the other hand, prescriptive grammarians (such as most editors and teachers) lay out rules about what they believe to be the 'correct' or 'incorrect' use of language."

Comment: (taken from http://forum.thefreedictionary.com/postst16684_How-Linguistics-definiton-of-grammar-and-syntax-differs-from-general-population-.aspx )

Comment: @MathieuK. Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: @user2268251,  it looks like it's prescriptive grammar (not the one used by linguists but by grammarians) that sits as judge of whether something is grammatically correct. It seems to be that prescriptive grammar that's the often subject of this forum, though sometimes it's a question of common usage instead. Ah, I see what you're getting at. Brilliant. Something that's grammatically correct but doesn't conform to the common usage satisfies one type of grammar but not the other, whereas common grammatical mistakes (comma splice, for instance) satisfies the other but not the one. Cool!

Comment: I don't think prescriptive and descriptive are the types of grammar relevant to this question. Rather, a definition that indicates what features of language are covered by "grammar" is important. To some people (including me), grammar deals with the structure or syntax of sentences but does *not* include other things like semantics and spelling, whereas other people think grammar covers all aspects of language. Whether a given sentence means what its writer intended or even makes sense semantically aren't questions of grammar.